# Finding documents that fit json input in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do a write statement that finds all the documents that fit the JSON data fed through a form. Here's an example of what the JSON looks like. I created a document on the database that has these exact same info and I still get nothing in return.

```
{
  type: 'Diamond',
  weight: '1',
  size: '1',
  color: 'Red',
  origin: 'Mexico',
  clarity: 'Translucent',
  shape: 'Pear'
}
```

and here's my code:

```
module.exports.renderSpecifics = async (req, res) => {
    const query = await req.query
    for (let key in query) {
        console.log(typeof key)
        if (Number(query[key])) {
            query[key] = parseInt(query[key])

        }
    }
    console.log(query)
    const campgrounds = await Campground.findMany({ query })
    console.log(campgrounds)

    res.render('campgrounds/index', { campgrounds })
}
```

the JSON after the for loop is the folllowing:

```
{
  type: 'Diamond',
  weight: 1,
  size: 1,
  color: 'Red',
  origin: 'Mexico',
  clarity: 'Translucent',
  shape: 'Pear'
}
```

Comment: Probably you are mixing number values with string values. In your example, your weight and size are defined as strings, but after the loop, they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

first you should create a model with mongoose Schema. The 'Model.findOne()' method should solve your problem.

Method Docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne